# Distance for location always return result 0 - ios sdk

Tags: ios, ios9, cllocationmanager, distance

I had calculate 2 location distance as below and the result always be 0 meters.
Can someone help?

```
double distance = [self.currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location1];
NSLog(@"Distance i meters: %.8f", distance);
if(distance <30)
{
    NSLog(@"Yeah, this place is inside my circle");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Oops!! its too far");
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Start by verifying that both `self.currentLocation` and `location1` are non-nil. `distance` will be `0` if either is `nil`.

Comment: did you see my answer @user831098  it's helpfull for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the correct result with the coding as below:

```
 CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:DEFAULT_LAT longitude:DEFAULT_LNG];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D annocoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location1.coordinate.latitude, location1.coordinate.longitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D usercoord = self.locationManager.location.coordinate;

   CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:annocoord.latitude longitude:annocoord.longitude];
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"LOC  = %f, %f", loc.coordinate.latitude,  loc.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"LOC2 = %f, %f", loc2.coordinate.latitude, loc2.coordinate.longitude);

    CLLocationDistance dist = [loc distanceFromLocation:loc2];

    NSLog(@"DIST: %f", dist); // Wrong formatting may show wrong value!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : Use `CLLocationDistance` for get distance:

```
 CLLocationDistance distance = [self.currentLocation distanceFromLocation:location1];
 float TotalMile=distance/1609.344;
```